# Can I transition a property of an element twice in css?

Tags: css

If I wanted to Change the width of an element twice and animate that. For example:

```
    box{
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
    }
    .box:hover{
        width:300px;
        width:200px;
    }
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Also if you make some research on google you can find a lot of tutorial, [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [keyframes animation](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/). It should works properly in your case.

like this

```css
    
@keyframes box-size {
  0%, 100% {
    width: 100px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 300px;
  }
}

.box{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background: pink;

}
.box:hover{
  animation: box-size 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```